# Run a few lines after map & reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce program(in Java) which finds count of words in a document and stores the output as:

```
word1 10
word2 20
...
```

I would like to know how to add a few lines to the end of the final output, (something like a finally block of a try and catch) that is I would like to append few words & their scores to the final output.

So my question here, is there a way to add a piece of code which runs after the execution of the reducer so that I may do something after the whole Map & Reduce completes?

Comment: Your reducer can always output additional lines as needed, I'm not sure there is a general way to say "when done, do some other stuff with the file just written"

Comment: @cricket_007 could you give me an example? I haven't seen that anywhere but I would like to do it in my application.

Comment: Example of what? `context.write` should already exist in your reducer. I said I **am not sure** if there is a way

Comment: If you have only one reducer, you can try append to the context. wordCount has many reducers, so I think you have to do this at the driver side.

Comment: Alternatively, leave your whole work flow the way you have it, then create a secondary mapreduce that reads that output and does the aggregate calculations (assuming that's what you're looking for), then writes to its own file (because you'll get an error that the output directory already exists otherwise)

Comment: @cricket_007 ya that's a possible work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***One Reducer :***  If you are having one reducer, then you can use the context object in the cleanup to write the rank/score for each word. But to do this, you need to have the data that is already written to the output file(word count). I'd suggest you to add a Map or some other object in reduce function to store the word counts. Use that Map object in clean up to find the rank/score and write the result through context object.

***Multiple Reducer :***  If you have multiple reducer, then you have to do the same only in main/run method. But in this case you'd have to read the output file data and then do the calculation before appending to the file. I'd suggest you to use combiners and use a reducer as suggested above to calculate the rank/score.

Comment: Good, shall try this.